# SSIS Expression to write the last previous month and year, assuming that current month is January

Tags: ssis, expression

I have this ssis expression:

```
@[User::Folder] + (DT_WSTR, 4)YEAR(GETDATE())+"_"+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) MONTH( DATEADD("MONTH",-1,GETDATE()) ),2)+".csv"
```

and it works

***"C:\Detalhe\2018_08.csv "***

But I think what will not work correctly in January 2019.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. This formula gonna take in January previuos year and december, should be everything ok:

```
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD("MONTH",-1,GETDATE())) + "_" + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)MONTH(DATEADD("MONTH",-1,GETDATE())),2)
```